# Disabled button enable when database total column and calculated value same vocation in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const [isSubmitButtonDisabled, setIsSubmitButtonDisabled] = useState(true);

let totalVal = 20000;
 
//get data
const getInvoiceData = () => {
  axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/cash/showInvoices").then((res) => {
      const getData = res.data.data;
      setInvoiceData(getData);
      console.log(getData);
    });
```

```jsx
<input
  type="text"
  Value={ 
    InvoiceData.map((ites) => {
      return ites.total == totalVal
        ? setIsSubmitButtonDisabled(false)
        : "true";
    })
  }
/>
<button
  type="submit"
  disabled={isSubmitButtonDisabled}
  className="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
  >
  Process Data
</button>
```

fetched data compare with total value , if it is true setIsSubmitButtonDisabled state will be false . then it implement to button disabled.

Comment: I think you just meant `disabled={isSubmitButtonDisabled}`. The `disabled` prop takes a Boolean argument, not a callback function

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but as far as I understood you are trying to compare the  data you fetched and set in invoiceData with the **totalVal** and toggle the diability of the button. You can try this

```js
const compare = ()=>{
 if(invoiceData.length === totalVal){
    return setIsSubmitButtonDisabled(false)
}else{
   return setIsSubmitButtonDisabled(true)
}
```

then in the button

```js
<button
  type="submit"
  disabled={compare()}
  className="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
  >
  Process Data
</button>
```

Please correct me if I have understood your question wrong